# How to convert ogg file to mp3 using python?

Tags: django, python-3.6, dialogflow-es, speech-recognition

I am trying to convert the Ogg file to mp3/wav formats. I used:

1. FFmpeg
2. pyaudio
3. dlls
   But nothing worked out.

Also, I am trying to first read the ogg data from an HTTP URL then want to convert it to mp3/wav, and then using speech_recognition converting to text.

If I don't use any method I get the following error.

Error: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if the file is corrupted or in another format.

Please suggest any libraries.

Code snippet:

```
audio_data = Data.get("audio")
    if '.wav'or'.mp3' not in audio_data:
        file = ("newspeech.mp3")
        new_audio = urllib.request.urlretrieve(audio_data,file)
```

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet?

Comment: This I am using the direct method to first retrieve ogg audio data from URL and write it in mp3 file but still getting the same error. Might be sure to of different encoding of ogg and mp3